# Writing to a file in Google Cloud ML

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Within my Tensorflow Python script, I want to write some debugging information that is too verbose for stackdriver logs, so I'd like to just write to my own file. If I do:

`f.write('my_file.txt', 'w+')`

I don't get any errors, which implies that I have some write permissions. However, I have 0 idea how to find this file. Is it in the `JOB_DIR`? How can i write to a file that is accessible once the job is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is written to the storage that is local to the VM that is running your code. If you want to access the file after the job has completed, you'll need to copy it to a GCS bucket at the end of your script. You can do so with the python google cloud storage client api:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.bucket(BUCKETNAME)

blob = bucket.blob(BLOBNAME)
blob.upload_from_file('my_file.txt')
```

In case that you are using TensorFlow, know that some TF io utilities can handle `gs://` blob locations as if they were filepaths. For instance, the `tf.keras` `Tensorboard` callback allows you to stream the Tensorboard log files directly to a GCS bucket, instead of you having to store them locally and upload them manually afterwards:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

# Define a callback that will store tensorboard log files in a GCS bucket
callbacks = [TensorBoard(log_dir='gs://BUCKET/BLOB')]
model.fit(..., callbacks=callbacks)
```

Comment: Is there any config I have to do for this? My job fails as soon as I try and create the client.

Answer (score 1):

Use the TensorFlow API to write a file directly to Google Cloud Storage:

```
with tf.gfile.GFile("gs://bucket/some/dir/somefile", "w") as f:
        f.write(result_str)
```